# Does passing a large component around actually use a lot of server resources?

Tags: c#, blazor

I've made an Avatar component for my gaming page, which since it is required for gaming I've put on the gaming section's layout page.

The Avatar control is quite complex, with several modes for choosing avatars from a gallery, selecting a color palette, and then displaying various versions of the chosen character (animated full-size svg, portrait thumbnail, etc.)

**My question is this: if I pass this component as a Cascading Parameter from the layout, am I actually persisting and passing entire rendered components, potentially 200Kb or more**, or just a reference to the class with whatever variables I've set, with it only "blowing up" when the component actually needs to be rendered?  (I'm guessing the latter)

Or, more importantly, what tools / steps would I need to use to determine for myself what's going on under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I actually persisting and passing entire rendered components

No, there is no need for that

> or just a reference to the class

Yes, for the C# part it's just a reference (same size as a long).

> [...] "blowing up" when the component actually needs to be rendered?

that depends a little. You have a shadow DOM that is rebuild (where needed) and the differences are applied to the actual DOM by JavaScript.

When you have large changes that could be I/O intensive for Blazor server, but SignalR is quite efficient.

Comment: ty for your comment.  It's a lot of markup, but not very heavy processing data-wise (mainly just rewriting a few hundred lines of svg code, about 100-200k worth).  I'm thinking I'm going to be fine just passing the thing around like a football.

Comment: You're still only passing a ref. It's the rendering you need to keep an eye on.

Comment: Yeah, I gotcha.  It's hard to look at like 1000 lines of code and realize that after conditional statements weed through it, and variables get inserted, it's only a couple hundred kb at most.  I was worried about using a lot of inline svg, because the resulting markup looks very long (up to 2000 lines), but the computer eats through that like popcorn.

Comment: I agree with @HenkHolterman.  If your only creating it once then it's all references from that point.